# Set Opacity When Moving UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

When moving a cell in my table in editing mode, the cell's opacity is set to be semi-transparent. This is done automatically without me setting anything. I would like to change this so it does not change opacity. I need the cells to be opaque so the subviews are clearly visible. I have looked at the `setSelected`, `setHighlighted`, and `setBackgroundColor` methods of the cell, but these aren't called when I begin to move the cell.

Any ideas?

Thanks